# Linking multiple plugins to same memory space

Tags: plugins, gnu-make, ld, linker-scripts, bare-metal

I'm developing a bare-metal embedded application; no OS or MMU. I'm using a toolchain that consists of arm-none-eabi-gcc, ld and make. It requires some plugins to be dynamically loaded/unloaded and I don't know how to create script for this configuration.

The host application has a defined API for plugin system, it consists of function declarations for *init_plugin()* and *execute_plugin()*.

There's several C files called plugin01.c, plugin02.c..., which are all implementing that defined API. I want to compile them and then place all plugins in exactly the same address space. There's only a single plugin loaded at once, so there's no problem with memory collisions. After compiling and linking I would extract these plugins from output file and load them separately into the target hardware.

I need help with solving two problems:

- Linker should not complain about multiple different definitions of same function
- Linker needs to place all code from pluginXX.c files into same memory range. It should reset the location counter after linking each plugin. It should assign same VMA and different LMA. Same VMA allows running plugin when it is loaded in that location, and different LMA allows me to extract compiled and linked plugins from output file.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe partial linking is solution to this, but is it guaranteed that non-plugin part of application (the host) will be linked the same way for each plugin? If some math lib code is placed on different address for different plugin linking, then the plugin code will jump into incorrect location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to solve it.

The problem of conflicts in symbol names was solved by prefixing all sections with .pluginXX string, and renaming symbols to pluginXX_init_plugin and pluginXX_execute_plugin.

The problem of placing all plugin code into same address space was solved by using OVERLAY feature of linker. All plugins linked together with the host with just one linker pass, which guarantees that everything is linked correctly.

Before this, I tried two-step linking by partially linking only host code into an object file, which would then be linked with each plugin separately. This was waste of time. During the partial linking step, unused code could not be discarded (--gc-sections option was not available together with partial linking --relocatable option) and code would not fit into available memory.